# Dockerfile build result is wrong when file is changed using Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, gitlab-ci

Found some strange behaviour while creating a image for spark. If I change a file that is being copied to the container, the container builds sucessfully but with the wrong content, with missing jars from the original image (the one in the `FROM spark:3.4.1-python3`).

My stack is something like this:

- Spark server (1 master and 2 workers) in kubernetes
- (Local) Airflow that sends jobs to the spark server
- Each airflow job uses docker operator and runs a docker container with spark-submit
- Gitlab does the CI/CD and builds docker image and pushes it to a private gitlab registry

So, my .gitlab-ci.yml is:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  only:
    - tags

  services:
    - docker:17.06.2-dind

  script:
    - docker build -q --no-cache --build-arg MINIO_KEY=$MINIO_KEY --build-arg MINIO_SECRET=$MINIO_SECRET -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

And my Dockerfile is:

```docker
FROM spark:3.4.1-python3

USER root

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq install -y python3-pip wget git

RUN wget -q https://mygit.com.br/api/v4/projects/341/repository/files/jars-spark.tar/raw?private_token=mytoken -O jars-spark.tar \
&& tar -xvf jars-spark.tar --strip-components=1 -C /opt/spark/jars jars-spark \
&& rm -f jars-spark.tar 

WORKDIR /opt/spark/conf
COPY ./log4j2.properties log4j2.properties

WORKDIR /opt/spark/app
COPY ./docrecon-landing-incremental.py docrecon-landing-incremental.py
COPY ./docrecon-bronze.py docrecon-bronze.py
COPY ./docrecon-silver.py docrecon-silver.py

COPY ./moviproc-landing-incremental.py moviproc-landing-incremental.py
COPY ./moviproc-bronze.py moviproc-bronze.py
COPY ./moviproc-silver.py moviproc-silver.py

COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --timeout 1000 -r requirements.txt --user

ARG MINIO_KEY
ENV MINIO_KEY=${MINIO_KEY}

ARG MINIO_SECRET
ENV MINIO_SECRET=${MINIO_SECRET}
```

I know that this very Dockerfile is not the best option, but this project has some particularities that makes difficult to think on other solutions.

If i change either the Dockerfile itself, or any of the files that are copied to the container, i get strange problems:

Inside the directory /opt/spark/jars/ should be original spark jars that comes with the image of the `FROM`clause plus some jars that i put there. Excepts that when I change some of the files that i mentioned earlier, it only has my jars!

Example:

for a tag 0.1.10:
[Complete jar set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhwgf.png)

and for the tag 0.1.11 after some file changes:
[Wrong jar set after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl169.png)

So, every time I try to execute a spark job:

```py
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Docker container failed: {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 1} lines Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
/opt/spark/bin/spark-class: line 97: CMD: bad array subscript
```

After some testing, I've noticed that this happens when I build and deploy the images through dind in gitlab, when I build and push in my local environment, the problem doesn't happen...
Also, I've noticed some errors on the gitlab runner logs about this job, but I don't think they matter since that happens even for the "correct" ones...